# Find position of minimum element in array

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

I've seen a lot of topics about finding position of specified element in array, but I can't apply their solutions to my problem or find appropriate.

I have a jagged array:

```
double[][][] _distance = new double[_mapSize][_mapSize][1]; 
//incorrect, but for clarifying array's structure
```

And I need to get indexes of minimum element.

If

```
_distance[2][5][0]
```

is minimum, I need to get "2" and "5"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
Tuple<int, int, int> minimumIndex = null;
double minimumValue = Double.Max;

for (var i = 0; i < _mapSize; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < _mapSize; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < _lastDimension; k++) {
      var current = _distance[i][j][k];
      if (current <= minimumValue) {
        minimumValue = current;
        minimumIndex = Tuple.Create(i, j, k);
      }
    }
  }
}

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", minimumIndex.Item1, minimumIndex.Item2, minimumIndex.Item3);
```

Comment: +1.  Not efficient at all, but if that's what he's looking for, there's no better way of accomplishing this.

Comment: I thought that there will be some better solution, but this one is acceptable. Thank you!